# Hide soft keyboard for specific TextField in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

My goal is to have a hidden Textfield which maintains focus so it can receive input from a Bluetooth barcode scanner. I have accomplished this so far, but the soft keyboard is always displaying which is a huge disruption in the application. I have tried using `dismissSoftInput()`, but the keyboard pops up for a moment before it is dismissed. I need to to never appear.

Right now, my code is

```
    @ViewChild("scannerInput") scannerInput: ElementRef;

    private _isRunning: boolean;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // as long as _isRunning is true, keepFocus will continue to call itself to make sure the input is focused
        this._isRunning = true;
        this.keepFocus();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // when the component is destroyed, keepFocus will stop running
        this._isRunning = false;
    }

    scanComplete($event) {
        var scan = <TextField>this.scannerInput.nativeElement;

        // Value of the barcode is evaluated here

        scan.text = "";
    }

    keepFocus() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // the input will receive focus every half second
            var scan = <TextField>this.scannerInput.nativeElement;
            scan.focus();

            if(this._isRunning)
                this.keepFocus();
        }, 500)
    }
```

and my HTML is

```
<StackLayout class="layout-container">
    <TextField #scannerInput 
        name="scannerInput"
        id="scannerInput"
        (returnPress)="scanComplete($event)">
    </TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

I've searched around for answers but none of them seem to fit my use case. I've found some solutions that disable the soft keyboard for the entire app/activity, however I need the keyboard in other sections of the app.

Answer (score 0):

The physical scanner device I'm going to use finally arrived this afternoon, so I was able to test it on a real device instead of an emulator.

Thankfully, the Bluetooth scanner seems to disable the keyboard by default; so the issue is "resolved".

I am going to leave this question open for now in case anyone has a software solution.